# Get contents of JSON file based on Todays Date

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have an app where different content will be shown every day **based on that date**.

*i.e. January 1 will have `picture1`, January 2 will have `picture2`, etc.*

I've locally got all the **data in the Days.json file**, and I know how to pull the **current date**, but I **can't figure out how to get the data for the specific date**.

*For example: pull in the picture and text for the day, and display it on screen*

Any ideas?  Will post any extra code as needed!

`**Days.json**` snippet:

```
{
    "days": [
            {
            "day": "Jan 1",
            "topic": "1 Endurance",
            "image": "picture1"
            },
            {
            "day": "Jan 2",
            "topic": "2 Endurance"
            "image": "picture2"
            },
            {
             "day": "Apr 18",
             "topic": "3 Endurance",
            "image": "picture3"
            }
            ]
}
```

`**ViewController.m**`

```
//Get todays date to match date format in Days.json
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSString *dateToday = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Date Today: %@", dateToday);
// Remove the year from current date string
NSString *dateTodayShort = [dateToday substringToIndex:[dateToday length]-6];
NSLog(@"Date Today Short: %@", dateTodayShort);

// Get the json file
NSString *JSONFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Days" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:JSONFilePath];
NSDictionary *JSONDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
days = JSONDictionary[@"days"];
NSString *day = [days valueForKey:@"day"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON is parsed as a dictionary with key "days" and an Array of objects as values. So you can iterate over the objects to find the one you want.

```
NSObjet *todayInJson;
for (NSObject *object in days) {
  NSString *date_object = [object valueForKey:@"day"];
  if [date_object isEqualToString:dateTodayShort] {
     todayInJson = object;
     //object found..
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Iterating that way make sense.  What would you do with `todayInJson`?  I think I know it would be something like `NSString *timToday = [todayInJson valueForKey:@"tim"];` but just wanted to double check with you on that.  Is that what you'd do there too?

Comment: Yes. Or todayInJson["day"]. Jsons can either contain  objects (same as dictionary) if they have { or arrays if they have [